# Determine a linear application fixed kernel and image

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I'm preparing for *Geometry and Linear Algebra exam* and I have encountered an exercise that I cannot solve. In particular, I'm asked to determine a *linear application* $L$ that respects two conditions:

- $\text{Im}(L) \; : \; y = 3\,x + z$;
- $\text{Ker}(L) \; : \; y = 2\,x + 2\,z$.

The first observation that would come to me is that the *image* and the *kernel* have dimension two, so the *domain* of $L$ must have dimension four, while the dimension of the *range* of $L$ could be assumed to be equal to three and therefore, in general, I would have $L : \mathbb{R}^4 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ of law:

$$
L\begin{bmatrix}
x \\
y \\
z \\
t \\
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b & c & d \\
e & f & g & h \\
i & j & k & l \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x \\
y \\
z \\
t \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

where the whole refers to the *canonical bases* respectively of $\mathbb{R}^4$ and $\mathbb{R}^3$. At this point, taking into account that $\text{Im}(L)$ is the *vector subspace* of $\mathbb{R}^3$ generated by the column vectors of the matrix associated with $L$, we have:

$$
L\begin{bmatrix}
x \\
y \\
z \\
t \\
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & c & d \\
3 & 1 & 3\,c+k & 3\,d+l \\
0 & 1 & k & l \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x \\
y \\
z \\
t \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

and taking into account that $\text{Ker}(L)$ is the *vector subspace* of $\mathbb{R}^4$ generated by the solution vectors of the associated homogeneous linear system:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & c & d \\
3 & 1 & 3\,c+k & 3\,d+l \\
0 & 1 & k & l \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x \\
y \\
z \\
t \\
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
0 \\
0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

which has as a solution:

$$
y = \frac{l}{d}\,x + \left(\frac{c\,l}{d}-k\right)z\,, \quad \quad \quad t = -\frac{1}{d}\,x-\frac{c}{d}\,z
$$

and this makes it impossible for me to assign any real value to the parameters for the second condition of the exercise to be satisfied. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If $L$ has size $n\times m$, then its image has dimension $n- 1$ and its kernel has dimension $m-1$. Therefore $m = m+n-2$ and $n=2$. This is a contradiction with the problem given, which gives $n,m \geq 3$, so it seems that there are no solutions.

Comment: Expressing these sets as equations, rather than sets, makes this question somewhat ambiguous. Obviously if we assume (and it is an assumption) that there are no variables other than $x,y,z$, then we are looking at an impossible map from $\Bbb{R}^3$ To $\Bbb{R}^3$. Adding a variable $t$ to the domain makes the kernel dimension $3$, not $2$, as the variable $t$ is now free (like how $x = 2y$ defines a line in $\Bbb{R}^2$, but a plane in $\Bbb{R}^3$). As SolubleFish points out, it really doesn’t matter how many variables you add: there is no solution.